# Gimp color tools (colorize, brightness, curves, etc) aren't working

Tags: gimp, image-processing, dialog, widgets

When I try to run color modification tools like right-click > Colors > Colorize (or any of the color tools, Brightness / Contrast, Hue / Saturation, etc). I click and nothing happens:

[image: Dropdown menu chain]

I click **Colorize** and nothing happens. The menu just goes away. Help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah ha, I just noticed this itty bitty error message at the bottom of the screen:

[image]

I forgot my image is in **indexed color** mode, not RGB! My PNG used to be RGB, but compression software changed it to indexed. To get all the color tools working again, just convert it back to RGB:

[image]

Now color tools work, hooray!

Comment: I feel a bit sheepish, but this gets me every time! I hope Google indexes some of these keywords so I find my own answer next time. :D

Comment: By the way, you can colorize an indexed-color image by editing its palette (manually). Especially if there are only 16 colors or less. It’s more customizable and resource-preserving.